# New Ethnicity variable using IPUMS data

Tags: r, mutate

New Ethnicity variable using IPUMS data

I'm trying to create a new Hispanic/Latino variable using IPUMS CPS data. Below is my code, the name of the variable is HISPAN, and the different codes I'm hoping to include as identifiers for Hispanic are

```
100, 102, 103, 104, 108, 109, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 610, 611, 612.
```

```r
Test_latino <- data %>% 
    mutate(HISPAN = case_when( 
    RACE == 100 & HISPAN %in% c(100,102,103,104,108,109,200,300,400,500, 
    600, 610, 611, 612)
```

I received the following error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in
```